# XCode 5 app validation and bundle identifier

Tags: validation, xcode5, provisioning-profile, xcode-organizer, bundle-identifier

I 've created distribution certificate and 2 provisioning profiles for distribution one with explicit App-Id and one with wildcard. I can see it in project build settings (and in Preferences>Account) and choose it in build settings for release: provisioning profile with explicit App-id.

I built archive with xcode 5 and try to validate it in organizer. But in dialog "Choose a profile to sign with" I can't see provisioning profile with explicit App-id, only this with wildcard. If I use the wildcard-profile the validation failed with message: "The bundle identifier cannot be changed from the current value, ('App-id'. ..." (The message only shows the App-ID suffix without Team-id prefix)

**Solved:**
The validation error message from Apple was confusing. I tried many things. The reason was a hyphen ("-") within the App-ID. After I had removed the hyphen and had created the provisioning profile with explicit App-Id the validation passed through.

Comment: Did you ever get this fixed?